# How to take derivative with respect to logarithmic function

Tags: differentials

I have a function g as a function of x; i want to take derivative of g with respect to ln x, 
i.e. dg/d ln x
where
g= a*x^2/(1+a*x^2/r^2)

Comment: Is this a question about math (or maths), or the software Mathematica?

Comment: Please do clarify if this is to be solved using Wolfram *Mathematica* or if I should migrate this question to [Math.SE].

Answer (score 3):

You have to do a transformation first:

$ \frac{d \textrm{ln(x)}}{d\textrm{x}}=\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow d\textrm{ln(x)}=\frac{d\textrm{x}}{x}$

Therefore,

$ \frac{d\textrm{g}}{d\textrm{ln(x)}}=\frac{d\textrm{g}}{d\textrm{x}}\cdot x$

Then you can proceed as normal. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi ! Unfortunately this answer does not rely on *Mathematica*'s capabilities and as such is more of a comment.

Comment: I think he is trying to solve this problem in _Mathematica_, but the derivative function in _Mathematica_ doesn't support directly inputing `D[g[x],ln(x)]`

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule. This syntax form is easily generalized.

```
D[g,x]/D[Log[x],x]
```

Comment: Your function `g` is not a function of `x`.

Comment: Ummmm... But the poster's was. How about D[function[x],x]/D[anotherFunction[x],x]?